Formative alternative to midterms for a large class
What is an effective, efficient, formative alternative to traditional midterm exams for a large introductory service course?
Constraints

No TAs to grade weekly assignments or run weekly exercise classes.
Only 10%-20% of the students are self-motivated; the rest are there just to pass the course.
You despise grading exam papers and prefer interacting with the students.
You cannot afford to spend more than 25% of your time on teaching this course.

Example
Next semester, I will teach an introductory course on Probability and Statistics to a class of about 60 students, mostly from engineering.  I have taught this course several times, but there are lingering problems:

I do not have TAs due to a lack of resources.
The great majority of the students see getting a passing/good grade as their primary objective.  This means:

They look for formulas they can memorize.
They primarily study to prepare for the particular type of questions asked on exams.
Cheating is widespread.


Because of the previous point, traditional midterm exams grossly distract the students and shift the discussion from "let's learn and have fun" to "how should I prepare for the test".  That is why I ask for more formative alternatives as opposed to summative tests.

What I have tried

Replacing two midterms with 5 in-class quizzes with lower stakes covering recent materials. Problems: (1) The quizzes take too much of the class time. (2) Grading takes too much time. (3) Not formative enough.
Shifting the exam questions towards more conceptual ones.  Problems: (1) The students complain that they do not get to practice on such questions. (2) The standard textbooks don't have a large supply of such questions. (3) Such questions do not cover all the skills the students are expected to learn.
For smaller (up to 15 students) non-service courses, I use oral exams in the form of exercise sessions.  The students receive the questions one week ahead and are allowed to collaborate to solve them.  During the exam, they are asked to declare which questions they solved.  For each question, one student is asked to show their solution on the board, and we discuss them all together.  Problem: This wouldn't work for large classes unless I have 4 separate sessions each with 15 students and scheduling such separate sessions would be a nightmare.


Welcome to ME.SE! I added the undergrad education tag, please correct if this is not at university or similar institute.

Your use of the term formative [assessment] is a bit different than my understanding. To me, it does sound like you're asking for summative assessment. [My perhaps overly simplistic understanding: formative is diagnostic, to help you teach better; summative is for grading.]

@SueVanHattum I want to give my students feedback to help them learn, and don't care much about the grades.  That is why I want to avoid standard (summative) exams.

This depends on your situation, but it might be worthwhile engaging with academic services at your institution. Sounds like you could go through a course design workshop. With a given set of learning outcomes, time and, resources (or lack thereof) a course design workshop should show how best to assess. This might also have the added benefit of formalising staffing shortages. If you need to apply a bandaid, do what you have to but definitely think about forward planning for the next academic year. Assuming your year starts in September, now is the best time to start the discussion for 2025

@fdcpp We have already fought that battle.  We are going to have exercise classes for the course in the Fall semester, but the Spring semester will still follow the old regime.

You are being over-worked and under-resourced and then trying to solve your institution's problems. Credit to you.

I really like this question because of the honesty about constraints!
I will give you my thoughts (from a student perspective).  Just trying to give you what thoughts I can.  For consideration, not strong prescription.  I don't have a silver bullet!
TLDR rec: Do ~3 period-long tests and a 2-hour final.  Suck it up and plow through it for the longer grading time (versus one period-long midterm and a 2-hour final).  Take the "less lecture time" as a positive (since tests are "in class drill") and COVER LESS MATERIAL.  Basically, something like your option 1.

For your reading (and from a real teacher):  https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1109&context=hmnj
[If you like it, he has two other excellent articles on his pedagogical philosophy, but they are in the context of calculus, so I didn't link them.  But brutally summarizing: (1) Do less well, not more poorly.  And (2) don't theory-push the engineering/science students in math service classes.]

"Probes and shafts" (as we flippant students called the course) is a vexing class in that there is so much to cover and you never really master the content.  You start with permutations and combinations which is kinda cool and has obvious applications to card playing...but then wham you're out of it and into statistics.  And in stats there are some central important ideas (normality, pdf, significance tests).  But it doesn't seem like you're really using the permutations from before.
And then there is sort of a blizzard of formulas for t tests, chi tests, t* tests, or whatever (I don't even recall them, just that they had slight differences in intent and formula).  Even if you give the kids a formula sheet or let them use functions in Excel or the like, it's still like a confusing set of black boxes. In contrast, a classical engineering-oriented calculus course is one where you still feel like you master every single integration technique.
The problem is really too much material, whether content itself (which can range from permutations to ANOVA) or foundations versus math drill versus application with real data.  It's just a lot.
It's not all bad, of course.  I generally find prob/stats an easier course (for science and engineering students) than courses like freshman chemistry or the calculus/ODE/engine-math sequence or some of the harder general junior-year engineering classes like thermo/fluids/EE.  Those are courses that weed.  I don't think probes and shafts weed engineers (maybe weed biologists...but then imagine a biologist in a survey EE course!).

Options:
Your first option (more tests):  I think the only serious issue here is the grading time.  Maybe try to think of how to format the exams so they are easier for you to process?  Or Pomerado through them?  I donno...but I feel ya.  I do think that more tests is better for making them less high stakes and for driving actual learning.
Also, I really disagree with the "loss of lecture time" complaint.  You should do a lot of in class drill during lecture...and tests are great in class drill.  Just cover less crap.  A random hour lecture of yours teaches me much less than the test cycle (to include my prep and the feedback from the graded result.)  As a student, I'm way more likely to remember a test I took than a lecture.
I'm not sure what "not formative" means. (Not even disagreeing, just don't understand the words.)
In a sense it is less realistic to real stats application, since you're not doing a project.  But I just think you have to leave projects for later courses (e.g. a Design of Experiments elective course).  There are too many issues with cheating/assistance and with having adequate support as the students work the projects.
Second option (concepts):  Yeah, that's a mistake for a bazillion reasons.  You need to pick your battles and go for imperfect wins, versus perfect losses.  Time-constrained plug-and-chug engineers are not going to appreciate this effort.  And not having the text/drill oriented to it is an extremely valid criticism.  I would try to make your exam questions crushingly similar to the drill problems.  Heck, maybe you don't have to curve that much!  And also maybe the students don't curse you so much. ;)
Sure, they won't be thinking about the more conceptual issues (which for sure are important in stats)...but at least they've had some exposure to the tools of the trade. E.g. I agree there's a lot of reasons why "p values are overrated".  But if you've never even heard/used/read the p value before, it's a step up to at least know the whole .05 thingie.
Third option (project-y oral exam-y):  I don't like it because you don't have the time to do it properly.  There are also all kinds of authorized and unauthorized assistance going on.
Fourth option (the base case):  You could just stick with midterm and final.  I don't like it as a student because of the stakes and worse pedagogy.  But it is less grading for you.  (Maybe still try to cover less material and do more in class drill.)

Thank you for your thoughts and suggestions, and the suggested reading.

The course is mostly "introductory probability" and less "statistics".  There are certainly issues specific to this subject (like the ones you mentioned) but here I preferred to focus on the issues that are common with other subjects like "calculus".  But the issues you pointed out are certainly valid and I agree with most.

Regarding the "not formative" complaint, I was referring to formative assessment.  I added an extra point in the example to clarify this.

Good luck. Can tell you have heart in right place.  And LOVE the HONESTY in describing constraints (to include your time)!

If anything, doing more probes and less shafts, maybe makes it easier to do drill problems and tests.  Since you don't need data sets to the same extent as with statistics.

Oh...and please...no Monty Haul...I hate it when people push that...it's such an "I'm a smart kid" thing.  (I do think that examples of game play and gambling can be very trenchant and relatable...but make them less tricky wording/concept related.  More on the don't draw to an inside straight.)

hehe... I like giving students puzzles, but I agree that Monty Hall can be more confusing than instructive.

You can certainly use quizzes that are automatically graded. I used MyOpenMath, which might already have what you need. Then you could quiz weekly, and give unit tests that you grade.
For other courses, I could say more. But I think it is inevitable that students will attempt to overuse formula memorization in stat.
(I've seen some great conceptual exercises in statistics, but I'm not finding them. Keep looking, if that's important to you.)

During the pandemic, my colleagues and I developed some automatically graded exercises on Moodle.  This is not a bad option, but the problem is you can ask only certain types of questions.

Thanks for telling me about MyOpnMath.  I will check it out.

You can make your own questions, but it takes a while to learn. I don't think the documentation is very good.
